# Button type button is triggered on enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is an already explained topic, but for some reason my input number triggers my button. I've read that if you put `type=button` it should not do it, but it still does. I've also tried to set `event.preventDefault()` and nothing seems to work.

```js
$(".buttonForNumber").on('click', function (evt) {
     alert("I'm here, I don't know why");
});

$(".numberToEnter").on('keyup', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        //do something....
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control numberToEnter"> 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttonForNumber">
    Button
</button>
```

Comment: In your case it would be `evt.preventDefault()`

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, added to the already tested code... It does not work either

Comment: I ran the code above and is fine, so I am not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I'm noting the unclosed input tag, that may be a problem

Comment: @jidexl21 input fields don't have a closing tag.  I'm assuming this markup is inside a `<form>`?

Comment: I make a new project, paste all the code and it worked for some reason... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: input tag should close like <input/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had my button inside a **form**, I removed the tag and it was solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("body").on('keyup', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        $(".buttonForNumber").trigger('click')
    }
});
```